# Suspceted error in declaration of list of lists, not sure how to correct

Tags: list, haskell

I am attempting to take a list of lists and print the maximum value found amongst all the lists. I have a function I believe should work, but I believe the way I am declaring the values is causing a problem.

```
nested_max :: [[Int]] -> Int
nested_max [] = minBound::Int
nested_max [[x]] = x
nested_max [[x,xs]]  = nested_helper [[x,xs]]

nested_helper [[x,xs]]= maximum (concat[[x,xs]])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `[[x,xs]]` is a list of length 1, containing as its unique element a list of length 2, containing elements `x` and `xs`. That's only one of the infinitely many possible shapes of a list-of-lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All patterns except the first one match with a *singleton* list: a list with one element. In that list you match again with a singleton list (so a list with one element that is a list with one element), and a list with two elements).

But you thus do not match with a list with an arbitrary number of sublists, nor with a list that has as first list a list with zero or more than two elements.

You however do not need to pattern match on the list, you can work with:

```
nested_max :: [[Int]] -> Int
nested_max = helper . concat
    where helper [] = minBound
          helper xs = maximum xs
```

We thus first concatenate the list of lists into a single list, then we check if that list is empty, in which case we return `minBound`, or we return `maximum xs` which will return the maximum of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the declaration `[[x,xs]]`, which is a list, which contains a list of two elements. This is not what you want, as it is not the general case - at some point you need the general case to match everything that you haven't matched yet.

You could try `lst:lsts` which matches the first element, the head, against `lst` and the other elements (if any) against `lsts` - this is the standard technique for recursion. We are not doing recursion here, so we can ignore this.

You could try `nlsts` which matches the list of lists in one go. Since you are passing one item to `nested_helper` and `concat` this seems to be the more natural and correct thing to do.

Thus:

```
nested_max :: [[Int]] -> Int
nested_max [] = minBound::Int
nested_max [[x]] = x
nested_max nlsts  = nested_helper nlsts

nested_helper nlsts = maximum (concat nlsts)
```

For completeness, there is a recursive version. This uses the `lst:lsts` form:

```
nested_max_new :: [[Int]] -> Int
nested_max_new [[]] = minBound
nested_max_new nlst = maximum (nested_helper_new nlst)

nested_helper_new :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
nested_helper_new [] = []
nested_helper_new (lst:nlst) = (maximum lst) : nested_helper_new nlst
```

Finally, in practical code we try to use `map`, `filter` and `reduce` - it doesn't much matter which functional language it is. This tends to provide the simplest and most readable code:

```
nestedMax :: [[Int]] -> Int
nestedMax nlst = maximum (map (\x -> maximum x) nlst)
```

NB: Like so many of Haskell's base functionality, `maximum` is a partial function, it doesn't work for all inputs. So you might prefer:

```
maxList::[Int] -> Int
maxList [] = minBound
maxList lst = maximum lst
```